# Create Module in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, module, laravel-5.3

I want to make a modulare laravel 5.3 application, I try to use `nwidart/laravel-modules` laravel package from composer, I follow this tutorial [laravel modules package](https://packagist.org/packages/nwidart/laravel-modules)  and it work, I have my Blog module created and the BlogServiceProvider class too.
But when I do `php artisan module:use Blog` I get this  error in composer `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Modules\Vente\Providers\BlogServiceProvider' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
here is exact solution for this

By default controllers, entities or repositories are not loaded
automatically.
You can autoload your modules using psr-4. For example :


 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
},

 1) copy the above code and paste it in your Composer.json
 2) then do composer dumpautoload
 3) then do  php artisan module:use blog
```

Comment: I'm looking into modules as well and was wondering what `module:use` does. Care to explain? :-)